# Tailwind JSx Image wont center on my cards

Tags: css, jsx, tailwind-css

I have made a set of three cards that will display information at the top of the three cards is an image, I am using JSX and Tailwind but can not seem to get the image to center, it sits off to the left.
How do I make it so the image is centered properly what am I missing? staring at it is not helping !

This is my code TIA !

```
    <section>
      <div>
        <h3 className='text-3xl py-10 text-center'>About Me </h3>
        <p className='text-center text-md py-2 leading-8 text-gray-800'>
          Blah blah blah  <span className="text-teal-500 text-md">Tech</span>  blah
        </p>

      </div>
      

      
      <div className='lg:flex gap-10 '>
      <div className='text-center shadow-lg p-10 rounded-xl my-10'>
          <Image src={design} width={100} height={100} />
          <h3 className='text-lg font-medium pt-8 pb-2'>Beautiful designs</h3>
          <p className='py-2'>

            Creating elegant designs suited for your needs

          </p>
          <h4 className='py-4 text-teal-600'>Design tools I use</h4>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>photoshop</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Aftereffects</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Blender</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Figma</p>


        </div>
      
   
        <div className='text-center shadow-lg p-10 rounded-xl my-10'>
          <Image src={design} width={100} height={100} />
          <h3 className='text-lg font-medium pt-8 pb-2'>Beautiful designs</h3>
          <p className='py-2'>

            Creating elegant designs suited for your needs

          </p>
          <h4 className='py-4 text-teal-600'>Design tools I use</h4>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>photoshop</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Aftereffects</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Blender</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Figma</p>


        </div>
        <div className='text-center shadow-lg p-10 rounded-xl my-10 '>
             <Image src={design}  width={100} height={100} />
        
          <h3 className='text-lg font-medium pt-8 pb-2'>Beautiful designs</h3>
          
          <p className='py-2'>

            Creating elegant designs suited for your needs

          </p>
          <h4 className='py-4 text-teal-600'>Design tools I use</h4>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>photoshop</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Aftereffects</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Blender</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Figma</p>


        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Let me know if this works: <div className='text-center shadow-lg p-10 rounded-xl my-10 flex justify-center'>

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work,

Comment: Let me know if the new solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** You are not assigning any styling that would center the image.

**Solution:** Use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to structure elements. (center the image in your case)

**Example:**

```
<div className='text-center shadow-lg p-10 rounded-xl my-10 flex flex-col items-center'>

          <Image src={design} width={100} height={100} />
          <h3 className='text-lg font-medium pt-8 pb-2'>Beautiful designs</h3>
          <p className='py-2'>

            Creating elegant designs suited for your needs

          </p>
          <h4 className='py-4 text-teal-600'>Design tools I use</h4>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>photoshop</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Aftereffects</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Blender</p>
          <p className='text-gray-800 py-1'>Figma</p>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, not sure how I missed that,

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to accept my answer if it answers your question :)! If you want to only have the image centered you would have to re-structure the html and only center the image container.